# Archiving and submitting using Xcode 10 legacy builds

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10, ios12, legacy-build-system

I archive apps through Xcode 10.X using the "Legacy Build System" for iOS 12 SDK? Will Apple approve if I submit these archived apps? Any drawbacks?

Answer (score 4):

i have build app last week with legacy build system and apple has approved and it is now live,  this is no drawback if we build application for iphone and ipad